# I want to get the downloading status on a file using Java, is there any way in java to do it? please read the full description

Tags: java-io

I'm want to read a file using java (I know the java IO utils can do the required), but the problem is: the file that i'm going to access has to get downloaded from a remote machine. So how would i know that the file download is completed or is it still going on?
i'm using a linux box. Is there any way to check the download completion status in java?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When the download method returns?

Comment: we have no idea on downloading... We only have a directory name with us and we just have to check whether it has a new file in the directory. If it has a new file and the file is copied totally the we have to move the file to another directory.

Answer (score 2):

I am using this to check the status whether a file being copied is completed. Maybe this helps for you as well. Correct me if I am wrong.

1. get the file size
2. wait for some time (say 1 sec)
3. check the file size
4. if the file is being downloaded at the moment then the new size will be greater than the earlier size; so repeat steps- 1, 2, 3 until you get the exact size.

Code sample

```
// sourceFile is the downloading file
if (sourceFile.exists()) {
    try {
        long size = sourceFile.length();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        long newSize = sourceFile.length();
        if (size < newSize) {
            while (size < newSize) {
                System.out.println("downloading...");
                size = sourceFile.length();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                newSize = sourceFile.length();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("File Downloaded");
        System.out.println("Size: " + newSize);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```